# Ошибка 'list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple' при построении массива для отображения лабиринта

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, анализ-данных, big-data, анализ

В университете дали задание создать лабиринт, как на картинке (фото), найти кратчайший путь от стартовой точки до финальной.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мой код:

```
from collections import deque
maze = [
        ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','T','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|','S',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-']
        ]


def print_field(field, path = None):
  field = maze.readlines()
n = len(field)
m = len(field[0]) - 1
s = None
t = None
for i in range(n):
  field[i] = field[i].strip()
  if field[i].find('S') !=-1:
    s = (i, field[i].find('S'))
  if field[i].find('T') != -1:
    t = (i, field[i].find('T'))

print_field(field)
print(s,t)

def bfs(field, S, T):
  n = len(field)
  m = len(field[0])
  INF = 10**9
  delta = [(0,-1), (0,1), (1,0), (-1,0)]
  d = [[INF]*m for _ in range(n)]
  p = [[None]*m for _ in range(n)]
  used = [[False]*m for _ in range(n)]
  queue = dequeue()

  d[s[0]][s[1]] = 0
  used[s[0]][s[1]] = True
  queue.append(s)
  while len(queue) != 0:
    x, y = queue.popleft()
    for dx, dy in delta:
      nx, ny = x+dx, y+dy
      if 0 < nx < n and 0 < ny < m and not used[nx][ny] and field[nx][ny] != '#':
        d[nx][ny] = d[x][y] + 1
        p[nx][ny] = (x, y)
        used[nx][ny] = True
        queue.append((nx, ny))
  print(d[t[0]][t[1]])
  cur = t
  path = []
  while cure is not None:
    path.append(cur)
    cur = p[cur[0]][cur[1]]
    path.reverse()
    print_field(field, path[1:-1])
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить?
Возможно, что я представляю вид лабиринта в неправильном формате, что тогда делать?

Буду очень благодарна за помощь!

Answer (score 3):

Ошибку была из-за того, что я забыла поставить запятые в конце каждой строки в массиве.